# null For input string: "c" Error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by: RNSVGPath

Tags: android, react-native, svg

I just built my react native project with react native cli but when I run it produce this error

I just have an svg file which want to render on screen via react-native-svg but when I adde it in my view it throw this error

[image]

my svg file

```
import React from 'react'
import Svg, { G, Path } from 'react-native-svg'
/* SVGR has dropped some elements not supported by react-native-svg: style */

const SvgComponent = props => (
  <Svg
    id="prefix__Layer_1"
    x={0}
    y={0}
    viewBox="0 0 159.2 133.7"
    xmlSpace="preserve"
    {...props}
  >
    <G id="prefix__Group_1">
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_1"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M0 84.5c10-.5 20 .6 29.6 3.1 18 4.5 34.2 14.1 47 27.5 2.7 2.9 4.1 2.7 6.8 0c102.1 96 125 85.8 151.8 84.5c2.3-.1 4.7-.5 7.5.6-4.7 4.2-8.8 7.6-15.5 8.4-22.9 2.8-41.8 13.8-57.6 30.4-4.3 4.5-8 4.6-12 .3-16.7-17.6-36.6-28.8-61-31.2-5.5-.5-8.4-4.8-13.2-8.5z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_2"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M15.2 68.4c21.3 1.7 42.2 9.8 60.7 24 3.1 2.4 4.9 2.7 8.2.1 18-14.2 39.8-22.6 62.6-24.1 1.8-.1 5.1-2 5.3 1.7.1 2.9.4 6.2-4.8 6.6-24 1.5-45 10.7-63 26.5-3 2.6-4.8 3-8 .2-17.5-15.8-39.6-25.2-63-26.9-4-.3-5.9-3-5.2-6.8.3-1.6.5-1.7 7.2-1.3z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_3"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M33.2 45.8c4.9 5.4 9.4 10.5 14 15.5 1.6 1.8 3.4 3.4 5.3 4.9 1.6 1.3 3.7 2.1 3.9-1.2.3-3.7 2.5-2.1 3.9-1.3 5.5 2.9 11 5.8 16.2 9 2.5 1.6 4.3 1.8 6.9 0 5.2-3.6 10.8-6.7 16.7-9.2 1.2-.5 3.1-2.1 3.4.8.5 4.8 3 2.7 4.8 1.2 5-4.2 9.2-9.3 13.5-14.2 1.6-1.8 2.7-4 5-5.1.3.3.6.4.7.7 4.7 11.5 5.7 12 17.7 8.5 2.1-.6 4.3-1.4 6.4-1.8 1.6-.3 4.1-2.2 4.5.6.3 2.3-.4 5.2-4 5.4-4.3.2-8.6.6-12.8 1.1-20.1 2.5-39.2 9.9-55.6 21.7-2.7 1.9-4.5 2-7.2.1a123.84 123.84 0 00-65.9-22.7c-1.4 0-2.7-.1-4.1-.4-2.8-.8-2.9-3.6-2.6-5.4.3-2.1 2.5-.9 3.8-.5 3.5.9 7 1.9 10.4 2.9 8 2.2 10 1.2 13.2-6.2.6-1.3 1.1-2.6 1.9-4.4z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_4"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M110.7 28.7c-.2 2.8-1.5 5.3-5.6 6.5-7.6 2.2-14.9 5.3-21.8 9.2-1.9 1.2-4.3 1.3-6.2.1-7.4-4.1-15.1-7.3-23.2-9.8-4.6-1.4-4.3-5-4.6-8.2-.3-3 2.2-1.2 3.3-.9 8.2 2.4 16.3 5.5 23.9 9.4 2.2 1.3 5 1.3 7.2 0 7.7-3.8 15.7-6.9 23.9-9.4 2.2-.6 3.8-1 3.1 3.1z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_5"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M53.4 43.4c7.8 2.4 15.3 5.7 22.4 9.8 3.2 1.8 5.5 1.6 8.5-.1 7.1-4.1 14.6-7.3 22.4-9.7.1 5.7-1.1 9.7-7.2 11.5-5.7 1.7-10.9 5-16 8.1-2.5 1.5-4.5 1.7-7 0-4.9-3.4-10.3-6.2-16-8.1-5.6-1.7-7.3-5.4-7.1-11.5z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_6"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M26 104.9c3.1-1.1 5.3.2 7.5 1.1 10.4 3.8 19.8 9.7 27.9 17.2 1.5 1.5 5.3 3.1 3.5 5.1-1.7 1.9-6.1 3-8.6 1-7.2-6.1-16.2-9.8-22.6-17-2.2-2.6-4.9-4.8-7.7-7.4z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_7"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M93.8 127.9c11.1-11.6 23.7-19.6 39.2-23.1-4.3 4.5-7.9 9.6-13 13.2-4.4 3-9.1 5.6-13 9.2-4.4 3.8-8.3 2.7-13.2.7z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_8"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M90.1 21.8c.1.8-.5 1.2-1 1.6-4.7 3.9-12.9 3.9-18 .2-2.8-2 0-3.6.3-5.3.4-1.9 1.5-3.2 3.7-1.9 2.8 1.6 5.5 2.2 8.7.5 3-1.5 6.5 1.4 6.3 4.9z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_9"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M79.7 0c1.7 2.7 5.3 4.8 2.8 8.3-1.1 1.6-3.8 1.4-5.1-.1C74.7 4.8 79.3 3 79.7 0z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_10"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M114.6 131.9c1.8-1.5 2.9-4.6 5.6-3.1 1.1.6 2.2 3.6 1.9 3.8-2.4 2-4.8-.6-7.5-.7z"
      />
      <Path
        id="prefix__Path_11"
        className="prefix__st0"
        d="M45.7 132.2l-7.9 1.5c0-2.6 1.1-4.9 2.6-5.3 2.1-.5 3.9 1.5 5.3 3.8z"
      />
    </G>
  </Svg>
)

export default SvgComponent
```

I think there my be a problem with 'c' chareacter in my svg. so I tried to lowercase the first occur of c character but that also not work

Comment: Remove paths till you figure out which one is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

If you're converting your SVG using this site (https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/playground/) then the problem is caused by SVGO optimisation.

Untick the enable SVGO button in the left-hand menu and the converted SVG it should render without an error.

[image]

Comment: Would have never found this without your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hello W.H.T, I tried for this solution but am getting same issue again.